# Function declaration in Python

Tags: python, function, theano

I am using Theano in Python.  I have the following code:

```
outtmp = trainfunc(some_parameters)
```

I cannot find any declaration of the `trainfunc` function, while I can only find a piece of code before the previous one as:

```
# Function compilation
trainfunc = TrainFn1Member(some_other_parameters)
```

I can find the declaration of `TrainFn1Member` but the two functions (`trainfunc` and `TrainFn1Member`) do not have the same signature (input parameters).

What does this mean, and is the second code segment the declaration of `trainfunc`?

Answer (score 3):

Mostly when name starts with uppercase letter then it is class name (unless it is completely upper cased, then it mostly means constant). There is no `new` operator in Python so this naming pattern is pretty important to distinguish functions from classes (anyway it is general pattern). I don't know Theano, but I suppose that `TrainFn1Member` is a class that implements `__call__` method, so you can call it's instance like a function. Search for `__call__` in `TrainFn1Member` class definition.

---

UPDATE:

According to your comment, `TrainFn1Member` is a function (what is pretty strange according to what I said above and what is not my idea ;)). In this case it has to return some `callable` what means that it returns one of 3 things (I hope I have not missed anything):

1. function (`def` or `lambda`)
2. instance of class that implements `__call__`
3. method of some object (function bound to some class instance)

As I don't know `Theano` at all, I can only suggest to search deeper being aware of those above.. (and welcome to Hogwarts ;))

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not a class. I can find the declaration as: def TrainFn1Member(parameters): ...

Comment: pretty strange (as of naming convention), but then it have to return a function or instance of some class that implements `__call__`. Only thing I can suggest in this situation is to go deeper.. ;) definitely `TrainFn1Member` generates some `callable`.

Comment: `TrainFn1Member` returns another function. Look at the source code for `TrainFn1Member`; there's probably a `lambda` or `def` statement in there.

Comment: if that `trainfunc = TrainFn1Member(...)` is from [here](https://github.com/glorotxa/SME/blob/master/FB_exp.py), then its 'a little' complex.. but [here](https://github.com/glorotxa/SME/blob/master/model.py) are some comments before function generation (might be useful probably, but I don't have more time now to discover what it really does, anyway I hope I helped a bit in taking good direction to find out)

Comment: theano.function() return a object that implement `__call__`. That is why it is callable. It is normal that TrainFn1Member don't take the same parameter as what it return, as TrainFn1Member build a python function with Theano.